# Communication between JADE agents AND siemens S7 1200 PLC

Tags: agents-jade, s7-1200, siemens

i would like to learn how I can make my agents communicate with a PLC(siemens S7 1200). Basically the agents are created in JADE and make a decision kind of a true and false decision which they are to send the PLC. If its true the PLC is activated or otherwise. I have heard of the concept of using simple object access protocol, but not familiar with it (if anyone knows how to use that they can help me with a sample program or means of linking my programs). To complete this by 08 April 2013

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about OPC.
OPC is an 'open' standard guarded and maintained by the OPC Foundation.

Every manufacturer of PLCs has an OPC server that communicates over their own protocol to their PLCs. The OPC clients can be donwloaded, purchased or created.
In short [S7-1200] *cable* S7 over ethernet *cable* [PC OPC Server *intern* OPC Protocol *intern* OPC Client]

In your case, you need an OPC Server from Siemens for the S7-1200. And the OPC client will be your agent. JADE needs to have a OPC library in order to communicate over OPC. See the website of www.opcfoundation.org for the possibilities.
Now you can read and write directly into the PLC.

But, you're using an S7-1200. The new micro automation PLC from Siemens. This has a new memory lay-out and OPC need some tricks to make it work. (Has to do with direct addressing in the older S7 PLCs and the named values in the S7-1200). The following FAQ from Siemens will help you further

How do you connect a PC station to an S7-1200 with OPC?
http://support.automation.siemens.com/WW/view/en/39960679

Or you could try sending the values via TCP/IP. This requires a reprogramming of the PLC.
CPU CPU Communication
http://support.automation.siemens.com/WW/view/en/20982954

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late but libnodave is a package for communication with Siemens PLC's. It works in Java too which is a great plus. I don't think it is suitable for industrial applications though. I do remember Siemens having their own version of the library. Just google it.